# VSTO remove file without resigning the manifest

Tags: vsto, manifest

I have a file added to my vsto project and I want to remove this file after publishing the project. This is because the file should only be avaliable for some customers, for others we want to remove the file.

Is there a way to remove the file without resigning the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.